# slide presentation change language of top title

Tags: r-markdown, presentation, slidy

I would like to get `Inhalt` instead of `Contents` in the lower left corner of a slide presentation.

I tried

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Erich Neuwirth"
date: "2022-09-28"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    incremental: yes
    pandoc_args: [
      "--variable=lang:de"
    ]
---

## R Markdown
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

but this did not work.

Comment: You just want to change the `Contents` to `Inhalts`  and everything else would be in English??

Comment: For my German slidy presentations thats the only English text visible all the time. Of course, bein able to change all slidy supplied texts to German would be better.

Comment: Well `Contents` could be changing to `Inhalt` using javascript actually. But I am not sure about other text if there's any.

Answer (score 0):

The lower left `Contents` could be changed to `Inhalts` using javascript code (sort of Brute-force way)

**presentation.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Erich Neuwirth"
date: "2022-09-28"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    incremental: yes
    includes:
      after_body: content-change.html
---

## R Markdown

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

**content-change.html**

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    var content = document.querySelectorAll(".toolbar a")[1];
    content.innerText = "Inhalts";
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this yaml head

```
---
title: "COVID-19 <br> Mathematische<br> und <br> statistische Analysen"
author: "Erich Neuwirth"
date: "29. September 2022<br><br><br><br><br>Informatiktag 2022"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    incremental: yes
    includes:
      after_body: content-change.html    
lang: de
---
```

everything works file.

`lang: de` changes titles and similarar things to German. It just does not replace the `Content` link in the lower left corner.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem and helps you, would you mark it as accepted and upvote it? : )